# Jquery Text Variable

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to get jquery to pick up variable that I am defining and I'm having issues doing it.

```
$.ajax({
url: "sitemap.php",
cache: false,
success: function(html){
    $("#results").append(html);
        var $seriestitle = $("#define-title").text();
    $('#results a:contains("$seriestitle")').addClass('current-series');
    $('a:not(".current-series")').hide();
}
});
```

This is the code I am using.  You can view the page at the following URL:

http://benjammindesigns.com/XML/details/1231.html

There is a span on the page, with the ID 'define-title', that contains text.  I am trying to pull the text from that span and use it as my variable.

Any info is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Actually, the `$` prefix is (by convention) reserved for variables that contain jQuery objects. It should be `var seriestitle = $("#define-title").text();`, since `text()` does not return a jQuery object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you want this:

```
var $seriestitle = $("#define-title").text();
$('#results a:contains("'+$seriestitle+'")').addClass('current-series');
```

Comment: Awesome, works perfectly.  Thanks, mkoryak

Just to further my understanding, what causes the need for the 'plus signs' and extra quotes on either side?

Comment: @Batfan: JavaScript does not do variable interpolation the way PHP does. Do not let the optional `$` in the variable name fool you.

Comment: @Batfan: I suspected you come from a PHP background. In PHP you actually can do a thing similar to what you have tried. It's called "variable interpolation". If you *don't* come from a PHP background, never mind. ;)

Comment: @Tomalak: Thanks you for explaining :)  I DO have some PHP background but it is very limited.  Does it require the extra quotes and plus signs because it is pulling a variable?

Comment: @Batfan: If you want to put it like that. It builds a dynamic string from the fixed parts + the variable content.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#results a:contains("'+$seriestitle+'")').addClass('current-series');
```

Answer (score 1):

The `span` you're trying to use is in the `head` of your document. Move it to the `body`.